# Codimension of infinite space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, differential-geometry, gauge-theory

Let $B$ be a finite dimensional manifold, $H$ be a complete Hilbert space and $V$ a finite dimensional subspace of $H$.

We set $\Gamma:=\Gamma(B;H)$, i.e. the smooth maps $B\to H$ and $W:=\{s\in \Gamma\mid \exists b\in B, \mbox{ s.t. }s(b)\perp V\}$.

If we regard $\Gamma$ as the infinite dimensional space and $W$ as its sub-space.

**Q**: Can we say that the codimension of $W$ is $\max\{\dim V- \dim B,0\}$?